# Image to fit screen size in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make an image stretch to fit the screen with preserverd aspect ratio. I thought this code would do the trick:

```
<Image Name="Viewer" Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"  Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"  Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both"/>
```

Regretably it seems like the image just fits to the width of the screen and crops it at the bottom.

The complete xaml code looks like this:

```
enter co<Window x:Class="ImageExplorer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageExplorer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" Background="Black">
<StackPanel>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Button Content="open" Click="OpenImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="58" Height="30" Margin="1,1,1,1" />
            <Button Content="Prev." Click="GetPreviousImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="58" Height="30" Margin="120,1,1,1"/>
            <Button Content="Next" Click="GetNextImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="58" Height="30" Margin="180,1,1,1" />
            <Label Content="Fil:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Height="30" Margin="1,1,300,1"/>
            <TextBlock Name="StiViser" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="298" Margin="1,1,1,1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Image Name="Viewer" Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"  Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"  Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `ViewBox` with `Stretch="UniformToFill"`?

Comment: No, but the solutin presented by Rise works fine. What I realy need is a good tutorial.

Comment: Do not bind the Image element's Width or Height! It makes no sense. The size is already set by the parent element if a proper one is chosen, i.e. a Grid or DockPanel.

Comment: That seems to be a valid point. I have removed the bindings and it makes no difference, it still works with the Dockpanel. Thank's for sharing this significant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DockPanel instead

```
 <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Button Content="open" Click="OpenImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="58" Height="30" Margin="1,1,1,1" />
            <Button Content="Prev." Click="GetPreviousImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="58" Height="30" Margin="120,1,1,1"/>
            <Button Content="Next" Click="GetNextImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="58" Height="30" Margin="180,1,1,1" />
            <Label Content="Fil:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Height="30" Margin="1,1,300,1"/>
            <TextBlock Name="StiViser" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="298" Margin="1,1,1,1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Image Name="Viewer" Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"  Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"  Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Works like a sharm!  
Now I just have to study the code to understand why. 
:)

Comment: Any explanation as to why this worked? Note: this also worked for my use-case