# How to resize content when maximize window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this window and I would like to resize content ( fit it to the size of window ) when the user maximize this window , I've tried many solutions but any of them worked for me :

```
<Window x:Class="Window_Image"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="550" d:DesignWidth="550">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Name="ImgDock"  Background="Transparent" >
        <Image Source="../res/myimage.png" Width="450" Height="450" x:Name="ImageComp"  Visibility="Visible" > 
      </Image>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

One of solution that I've tried :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990733/19442413

Unfortunatly , this solution didn't works for me.

Comment: To have content automatically adjust to their containers, I usually use grids, assuming you have other controls besides your image.

If you only have your image, but wanted to keep the image ratio, use the stretch property instead of width/heigth

Comment: I've only image , I've posted all code of my window

Comment: Ok, then could you try removing the Height and Width properties, they should not be needed.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you're manually fixing sizes in WPF you are *probably* doing something wrong. Most of the time the only fixed values you will want/need are for margins/paddings and maximum/minimum sizes. You might need some fixed values for more advanced use cases but I've rarely used to manually manipulate those in 7+ years

Comment: Try ViewBox which will visually resize content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the `Image` size was hardcoded (`Height` and `Width` properties).

By default, most of WPF's component will adjust their size to fill their containers.